# Selenium2: C#: Help with while loop

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I need help with while loop, below there is a code of page where I have do it:

```
<div class="list">
<span class="destination">
<a tabindex="20" href="/flights-to/uk/cheap-flights-to-united-kingdom.html">United&nbsp;Kingdom</a>
</span>
<span class="destination">
<a tabindex="21" href="/flights-to/es/cheap-flights-to-spain.html">Spain</a>
</span>
<span class="destination">
<a tabindex="22" href="/flights-to/us/cheap-flights-to-united-states.html">United&nbsp;States</a>
</span>
<span class="destination">
<span class="destination">
<span class="destination">
<span class="destination">
<span class="destination">
<span class="destination">
<span class="destination">
<a tabindex="29" href="/flights-to/belf/cheap-flights-to-belfast.html">Belfast</a>
</span>
</div>
```

I have to prepare script which will be clicking on each links and check if there is no e.g. 404 error.

I can do it in Selenium IDE, but I don't know exactly how I should start with C# and Selenium2. Maybe anyone have some tips?

Comment: Hi, I know that I should count size of all elements in frame, next I have to use loop (while) and then add commends Selenium.navigate().back. Sorry for that stupid questions but I don't have a experience in Selenium2.

Comment: I don't think that the elements will persist once the browser has moved to a new page. You'll probably need to find the first element, click it, navigate back, find the next one, click it, etc. Is your question about how to find an element with Selenium, how to navigate back, or how to write a `while` loop in C#? What code have you written so far, and how does it not do what you want it to?

Comment: It might be better to extract the URLs for each link and visit them in turn. Once you click the first link and navigate to a new page the other link elements will be invalid to your Selenium session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
string url = "testpageurl";

IWebdriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

var links = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));

for(int i=0; i<links.Count; i++ ) 
{
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a"))[i].Click();

Assert.IsFalse(driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body")).Text.Contains("404"));
}
```

Comment: Hi Ivo, this is exactly what I need, after small modifications everything looks as I expected. Thanks